# Is there a way to send an email without rerouting to a different page using just html/css?

Tags: html

I'm trying to make a html page that sends an email when one clicks submit. The only methods I have been able to find reroute to the mail server's page. I'm not familiar with php or javascript yet and I'm using firefox browser.

Comment: You really can't do this without either loading a page that runs a server script to send the email, or using something like a Javascript ajax request to talk to a server component for you without leaving the current page.

Answer (score 0):

You can send an email using ajax request.

visit the following link to see how you can use ajax to send an email with your form data in post:

http://teachingyou.net/php/simple-php-contact-form-using-ajax/

Hope this helps!